# json_decode all the array values of an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array similar to:

```
[ "id" => "90bbc6f8"
  "user_id" => "7a88a06f"
  "country" => "Greece"
  "region" => null
  "users" => "[]"
  "emails" => "[]"
]
```

but having hundreds of values, I need to decode the arrays like "users" and "mails", is there a way to apply json_decode to the values without going through foreach loop? paying attention to the performance

Comment: This is a php array definition, not a json. 
Maybe you mean json_encode instead?
users and emails are defined as string not as array.

Comment: I need to decode the values like "[]" in the array,  json_decode converts string to array, and I need instead of having "users" => "[]" as string , to have "users" => array()

Comment: Well you won't get that because what you've shown us isn't JSON, so json_decode can't decode it. Do you have some actual JSON instead of this PHP snippet? And even if it was closer to valid JSON, `"[]"` won't be turned into an array by any decoder - it's just a string so it'll be treated as one. Either make sure in the initial JSON that it's shown as `[]` without the quote marks round it, or write your own additional code to look for any such strings remaining after the initial decode, and replace them with empty arrays.

Comment: e.g. if we make this into a valid, decodable JSON object, and then decode it, what you get back is as shown here: https://3v4l.org/XSCbv - i.e. the same as the array you've shown us above. So your task now would be to find all `'[]'` strings in the data and replace them with arrays. But I'd say it would probably be simpler to ensure the JSON you're decoding is correctly formatted to begin with.

Comment: _"is there a way to apply json_decode to the values without going through foreach loop?_" - you mean like, `$users = json_decode($yourArrayVariable['users']);` ...?

Answer (score 1):

This does the work

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $myArray,
    function (&$value, $key) {
        if (in_array($key, ['user', 'email'])) {
            $value = json_decode($value, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
        }
    }
);
```

array_walk_recursive will scan the whole array, then the function will json_decode the value only in the key is user or email.

Notice the &$value in function call, this bind the value to the original one of the array.

You didn't specify it, but I guess that sometime user and email contains data and are not always "[]" in this case you need json_decode.
Otherwise, you can replace json_decode with

```
$value = [];
```